# Friends within an application that can be both application users and non-users - how to design the data model?

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am writing an application in which application users can add friends with whom they can later share things inside the app. The thing is that they can add friends who are already using the application (easy case) but they can also add people who are not yet using the application but might start doing it one day (the tricky part). In the latter case they can simply add a record in the app and then share it via email but the record still needs to be stored in a database. An important thing to mention is that whenever a user adds a record for a friend a record is added for him/her as well (because they are sharing stuff I need to add information about user's part as well).

If friends could only be application users, then I would simply have a User table and a junction table defining the many-to-many relationship between users. Then, the record table could look somewhat like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Record (
    record_id INT NOT NULL, -- primary key
    record_col VARCHAR(45) NULL, -- some column describing the record
    added_by_id VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, -- references user_id from the User table
    added_for_id VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL -- references user_id from the User table
);
```

However, since one can add friends who are not application users and can then add records for them I think I need an additional table to store information about friends:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Friend (
    friend_id INT NOT NULL, -- primary key
    friend_col VARCHAR(45) NULL, -- some column describing the friend
    friend_of_user_id VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, -- id of the user who added this friend
    is_user BIT(1) NOT NULL, -- boolean indicating if this friend has already created an account
    friend_user_id INT NULL -- if above is true, user_id of this friend would go here
);
```

But then how do I handle this in the Record table? I could have some records added for application users and some for non-users so for some of them the foreign key would reference user_id and for the rest friend_id. This doesn't seem right to me...

I could also try putting everyone (both application users and non-users) in a single table but then for the same physical person (let it be John Smith) I would have potentially multiple records added by different people who are friends with John and a record representing the actual John Smith being application user. This seems nasty.

What am I missing here? This doesn't seem like an unusual thing to do and yet I cannot figure out a proper solution.

Comment: You could create stubs in the user table for people who haven't yet created their accounts. Friends would then just be a join table between pairs of users.

Comment: Let's go back to John Smith. He is not a user yet but two people add him as a friend because they want to share something with him. One of them adds him with display name "John Smith" and the other one as "My love" (let it be his beloved). Additionally, one person adds him with his personal email and the other one with his office email. If I want to store this somehow I need two separate records in the database. Additionally, if John Smith creates an account with his personal email I can update one of these records with proper data but there is no way for me to update the other one.

Comment: If the user gets to pick their own display name for each of their friends, it should be a field in the join table. If two people have the same friend, that's determined by their *email*. When John Smith creates an account, it fills in the rest of the fields for the record matching whichever email they sign up with in the user table. If you want multiple emails to relate to one user, you need another table to represent that, but think about it: you can't know that until they create an account and demonstrate they own all of the emails.

Comment: But broadly: designing your data model needs a lot of information about what functionality you need to implement, and is too coupled to your specific case to be useful for SO and the mythical future visitor.